# avoid Sheet desactivate until workbook is saved and closed

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with several sheet containing auto hide when changing sheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
Me.Visible = xlSheetHidden
End Sub
```

I've put a button with macro to copy one of the sheet and rename it.
I need to keep it visible so I can go in my "Index" sheet and set up an Hyperlink to the new sheet. Actually I can't cause it is hidden as soon as I go to My "Index" Sheet

Code to copy:

```
Sub NouvelleFiche()
    Dim shtName As String
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Sheets("blank").Visible = True
    Worksheets("Blank").Copy after:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count)
    Set wks = ActiveSheet
    Do While sName <> wks.Name
        shtName = Application.InputBox _
          (Prompt:="Enter new worksheet name")
        On Error Resume Next
        wks.Name = sName
        On Error GoTo 0
    Loop
    Set wks = Nothing
End Sub
```

Is there a way to include in the Sub NouvelleFiche() a line to stop Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate() until workbook is saved and closed than deactivate will be fonctionnal when reopening file as long as I don't call the Sub NouvelleFiche() ?

Comment: Try `Application.EnableEvents = False`

Comment: You could put a "flag" value in a cell immediately after the copy eg `wks.Range("AA1").value="x"` then in the event handler: `If Me.Range("AA1").Value <> "x" Then Me.Visible = xlSheetHidden`   Clear the "x"  when you're ready for the sheet to be hidden.